# How to compare a command with an integer?

Tags: bash, shell, variable

For example I declare a variable, which should return a current hour
`` var=`date +'%H'`. ``
And then I would like to compare it in if-statement `if ["$var" -eq "23"]; then echo "$var = 23"; fi`

But it doesn't work. How can I solve it?

Comment: Spaces are very important, you need one after `[` and before `]`, those spaces are mandatory.  You can try it on [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) to handle many of these types of errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use more spaces around `[` and `]`

Comment: awesome! spaces were the issue in my case!

Answer (score 2):

Couple of pointers:

- don't use backticks, use `var=$(date +%H)`, this is far more readable
- use spaces between square brackets and variables: `[ "$var" -eq "23" ]`
- consider using logic operator `&&` instead of `if`. `[ $var -eq 23  ] && echo "var is 23"`